# SQL Server cannot be installed in VS Code: loading hostfxr.dll failed

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code, new to SQL, programming in general. But, I am trying to install mssql in VS Code. It's not working - its says Azure Pipelines failed. In the terminal it says;

The library hostfxr.dll was found, but loading it from c:\Users\rimini201.vscode\extensions\ms-mssql.mssql-1.9.0\sqltoolsservice\1.9.0\Windows\hostfxr.dll failed

Any ideas please?

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two completely different products. None of them is installed through VS Code. Did you try to install a SQL Server extension and got an error? Which extension?

Comment: replaced "SOS!!" with some actually useful title content.

Comment: Its OK I sorted it out. Thanks for your helpful comments